# How to make external API call to Yelp in Node.js/Express/Angular app

Tags: angularjs, node.js, api, express, yelp

I am trying to make an API call to Yelp in my Node.js app. I saw from here that I should use this code in order to be able to use the Yelp API: https://arian.io/how-to-use-yelps-api-with-node/ . I used that code in my app.js file. Now in order for it to display the results on the browser I know that I have to connect the controller to the view (in my case index.html) and bind the two files with $scope. But I would also have to somehow connect the controller to app.js. The tutorial that I followed on arian.io said:

> Now if you call the function request_yelp(params, callback) it will call the callback with these arguments, callback(error, response, body).
>    That's it, now you're ready to take full advantage Yelp's API.

but how or where do I call that function? I assume I'd do it in my controller but I have tried that but it didn't work.

To summarize my issue, if the API call is right and it is where it should be, then my next step is to link that with my controller, once those two are connected, I have to bind html with apiController.js with $scope in order to bring my data results to be displayed in the browser. I know I am missing a lot of things, but I think I have the right idea.

Any help is welcome. Thanks!

```js
   My app's tree 

>.git
>bower_components
>client
    >controllers
        -apiControllers   (My one and only controller)
    >css
    >views               (This is empty)
    app.js
    index.html (This is my one and only page/ my app is a one page app)
    package.json
>models
>node_modules
app.js    (This is where I am trying to make the API call)


<-- ================================================== -->

 //This is my app.js file


    //Call packages needed
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();                   
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var dotenv = require('dotenv').config();
    var oauthSignature = require('oauth-signature');
    var n = require('nonce')();
    var request = require('request');
    var qs = require('querystring');
    var _ = require('lodash');

    // Function for yelp call
    var request_yelp = function(set_parameters, callback) {

      var httpMethod = 'GET';

      var url = 'http://api.yelp.com/v2/search';

      var default_parameters = {
        location: 'New+York',
        sort: '2'
      };

      var required_parameters = {
        oauth_consumer_key : process.env.yelp_consumer_key,
        oauth_token : process.env.yelp_token,
        oauth_nonce : n(),
        oauth_timestamp : n().toString().substr(0,10),
        oauth_signature_method : 'HMAC-SHA1',
        oauth_version : '1.0'
      };

      var parameters = _.assign(default_parameters, set_parameters, required_parameters);

      var consumerSecret = process.env.yelp_consumer_secret;
      var tokenSecret = process.env.yelp_token_secret;

      var signature = oauthSignature.generate(httpMethod, url, parameters, consumerSecret, tokenSecret, { encodeSignature: false});

      parameters.oauth_signature = signature;

      var paramURL = qs.stringify(parameters);

      var apiURL = url+'?'+paramURL;

      request(apiURL, function(error, response, body){
        return callback(error, response, body);
      });

    };

    app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/client'));

    app.get('/', function request_yelp(params, callback){
        res.send('This is the main page');
    });

    app.listen(3000);
    console.log('Running on port 3000');


<-- ================================================== -->
<!-- This is index.html. Here I would like to display my YELP responses. I am using Bootstrap

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
      <!-- <div class="container-fluid"> -->
      <!-- <div class="jumbotron"> -->
                  <div class="row-fluid">
                      <!-- <div ng-controller="MainCtrl"> -->
                            <p><date-input name="info.name" message="info.message"></date-input></p>
                <div data-ng-repeat="business in businesses">
                             <!-- <div class="col-lg-offset-1"> -->
                            <div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-3 col-sm-2 col-xs-6 text-center">
                                    <p>Breakfast</p>
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <img class="img-responsive img-circle" src="{{business.image_url}}">
                                    <h5>{{business.name}}</h5>
                                    <h5>{{business.rating}}</h5>
                                    <h5>"{{business.snippet_text}}"</h5>
                                    <h5>{{business.categories[0]}}</h5>
                                    <p><a class="btn btn-link btn-sm" href="{{business.url}}">View details &raquo;</a></p>
                                    <p><a class="btn btn-xs btn-info" id="breakfast" role="button" onClick="refreshPage()">I don't like this one!</a></p>
                                </div><!-- End thumbnail -->
                            </div><!-- End col-md-4 -->


<-- ================================================== -->

// Finally this is my apiController.js. What code do I need here to connect the API call to my view? 

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope'function($scope) {
    $scope.total = [];
    $scope.businesses = [];

}])
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, I'm going to make a series of observations before I attempt to answer your question.

Your `app.js` file seems to be doing too much. I understand that you want to make a single page app, but some structure could help. It will be nice if you let your `app.js` file handle the application bootstrapping logic. That is connecting to your database and firing your express server

```
  var express = require('express'),
    routes = require('./routes'),
    app = express();

  /*load application  middleware here */

  /*Connect to databse, if needed */

  /* load routes */
  routes(app)

  /*Fire up the server */
  app.listen(3000, function (){
      console.log('Server listening on port 3000');
  });
```

You need to have a controller that handles the making of any external API calls as well as saving to your database. The controller file is where you will make your API call, in a method of some sort.

```
    module.exports = {
        makeApiCall: function(req, res) {
            /* return response after call */
        }
   }
```

After you set up your controller, you will need to expose the functionality on a route, like so:

```
var controller = require('./controller');
  module.exports = function(){
      app.get('routes/segment', controller.method);
      /* load more routes if any */
  }
```

Then in angular you need to create a service that makes a call to the route segment on your backend and returns the response. You'll inject the service into your controller and make the controller available on your page however is more convenient for you.

Ex. `Filename.service.js`

```
angular.module('MyModule')
    .service('ServiceName', ['$http', 'anotherDependency', ServiceFunction]);

function serviceFunction ($http, anotherDependency) {
    return {
        $http.get('route/segment').then(function (res) {
            /*return response, promises are better */
        }, function (err) {
            /* Return error if any */
        });
    }
}
```

`FileName.controller.js`

```
angular.module('MyModule')
     .controller('MyController', ['ServiceName', ControllerFunction]);

  function controllerFunction(ServiceName){
       var vm = this;
       ServiceName.makeCall().then(function (res){
         //set result on vm to make it accessible on your view.
       }).catch(function (err)) {
         //report error if any
      }
  }
```

Then on your view, you can load the controller using the `Controller as` Syntax.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, this helped a lot.